# How to create a custom progress bar with attached button on it with scrolling functionality in android

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar, uiprogressview

I have to implement a progress bar as given in image. It should work on change the position of button over it. Here i need to change the brightness of image by this progress bar. If user move that button to left then image brightness should go to dull and to right side then image brightness should go to fine  as movement of that button. I need both functionality to this progress bar implementation and way to get GUI like this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did u try SeekBar?

Android Widget http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html

Comment: are all functionality achieved by seek bar which are required to me.

Comment: @Shrikanth-  First of all thanks to guide me that it will happen by seekbar not with progress bar. I have applied all functionality but it is making device screen dark black at left most point of seek bar. it is also not working at first time as required after it it is working fine. Have you any ides why it is happening.